# Наличие или отсутствие точки с запятой в теле функции

Tags: c++, функции

При определении функции с пустым телом, как правильнее написать её код и зависит ли от этого "логика" самой функции?
Если разницы нет, то есть ли разница в производительности, читабельности кода и т.п.?

```
foo(){}
```

или

```
foo(){;}
```

И, если не затруднит, объясните подробно.

Comment: Без разницы....

Comment: {} чище и визуально менее "шумно". В скомпилированном виде разницы нет.

Comment: второй вариант - первый раз такое вижу.

Comment: Пустое тело - ок. Зачем добавлять еще и пустую инструкцию? Абсолютно незачем. Используйте первый вариант.

Comment: Я-юниор, поручили проревьюить код за сеньером. Тоже не вполне понимаю, зачем, но решил, что просто так опытный разработчик совершать ошибку не станет, (к примеру, код с ; мог быть более безопасен чем обычный с {})

Comment: может у синьора и спросить? вполне возможно, что до этого он программировал на каком то хитром диалекте с++, где эта точка с запятой имела значение или у него был наставник, который бил по пальцам за отсутствие этой самое точки с запятой.

Comment: я придумал, зачем это может быть нужно - человек явно помечает функции, например, что бы показать, что она уже полностью написана (или наоборот, требует дописывания).

Comment: Спросил у сеньера. Так код выглядит эстетичнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разницы совершенно нету, просто в первом случае читается проще. Второй же вариант мало того, что выглядит не очень, так еще и содержит мусор в виде пустой инструкции